# java.lang.NullPointerException When Doing A Read in HDFS

Tags: hdfs, hbase

I have had a 10 node HBase cluster up and running for the past 4 months. The cluster was setup on VMs in a corporate environment which I do not control, but everything has been working great...until today.

Today, every part of the system was down. I restarted the system and everything came back up for a bit, but then would go down again (particularly HBase...but I think that was because of this following issue).

There is an error in the HDFS logs that says:

```
HdfsCanaryCdh4{hdfs://hbase-1.internal:8020} for hdfs://hbase-1.internal:8020: Failed to read /tmp/.cloudera_health_monitoring_canary_files/.canary_file_2014_04_15-17_39_25. Error: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.lang.NullPointerException): java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.DatanodeManager.sortLocatedBlocks(DatanodeManager.java:334)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocations(FSNamesystem.java:1343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.getBlockLocations(NameNodeRpcServer.java:413)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.getBlockLocations(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:172)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java:44938)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1002)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1752)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1748)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1438)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1746)
```

When I jump onto the Name Node and run:

```
sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfs -cat /tmp/.cloudera_health_monitoring_canary_files/.canary_file_2014_04_15-17_39_25
```

I get back a single line that says: `cat: java.lang.NullPointerException`.

I also double checked that the disks weren't full (they aren't) and that I have connectivity (everything appears normal - nobody has touched this system as I was the only one with access).

I am completely stumped what is happening here. I can provide more details if needed, but I'm not even sure where to go from here.

**Update**

Per Mark's request in the comments, the output of:

```
sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfs -lsr /tmp/
```

is

```
drwxrwxrwx   - hdfs supergroup          0 2014-04-16 09:48 /tmp/.cloudera_health_monitoring_canary_files
-rw-rw-rw-   3 hdfs supergroup         56 2014-04-15 16:59 /tmp/.cloudera_health_monitoring_canary_files/.canary_file_2014_04_15-16_59_24
[continues like this for all the files in the directory]
```

Comment: Did you have an answer for this question? I have exactly the same problem.